# column "" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have looked into questions similiar to this, but have still not found an answer. Basically for my database I need three tables but when creating my last table (race_schema) I get an error. "column "carid" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist". I have tried various different things and edited the code, but nothing seems to work. Could anyone help me out?.

```
car_schema = """
carId VARCHAR NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(carId)
"""

track_schema = """
trackId VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
trackLength INT NOT NULL,
lap_distance DECIMAL NOT NULL
"""


race_schema = """
raceId VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (carId) REFERENCES car(carId),
FOREIGN KEY (trackId) REFERENCES track(trackId),
lapIndex INT,
```

Comment: You have discovered the issue with mixed case identifiers. If you insist on using them then it needs to be `REFERENCES car("carId")` and the same for the next FK. Read this section of the docs [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please don't add tags for DBMS products not involved

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Since it case folded down I'm saying Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yea sorry it is Postgres